# quote by placing > at start of line in python?

Tags: python

I need to do a or linebreak add 2 spaces at end

Comment: Dynamically allocated (and reallocated) arrays? Stacks? Double-linked lists? Recursion (which is really a form of stacks as well)? There are plenty of alternatives if you just search a little.

Comment: Besides that, where did you get the assignment or exercise from? From a book? From a teacher? Haven't they mentioned anything that could be useful?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some sort of [Realloc()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function. This function is used to extend the allocated size. The program should be something like that:

1. Allocate default value with malloc.
2. Read next number from your input.
3. If you got the number and this is not EOF (End of file), then use realloc to extend the allocated size by 1 and put the new number at the end.
4. Keep doing this untill you reach EOF.

Of course this is just one solution, and there may be others.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is some kind of a trick without using `realloc()`. You can read your file twice.

1. Open a file
2. Iterate through its content and find a size of the future array
3. Close your file
4. Allocate memory
5. Open a file again
6. Read numbers from the file and fill your array

P.S. In the future, try to be more specific while writing questions titles.